# Splitting a card deck of 100 cards into two decks of 50 cards

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

Consider a card game with $100$ playing cards, of which exactly two cards are Jokers. After a good mix, the cards are divided into two piles of $50$ cards each. These are referred to as $Pile1$ and $Pile2$.

Suppose we get the information that at least one of the two jokers is in $Pile1$. What is the probability that the other joker is also in $Pile1$?

We will call the jokers now $Joker1$ and $Joker2$. What is the probability that $Joker2$ is in $Pile1$ if we already know that $Joker1$ is in $Pile1$?

So for the first question we know that one joker was already drawn so we use the Hyper-geometric distribution to find the probability of drawing the second one: $Hyp(99,1,49)(\{1\})$ so we are drawing $49$ from $99$ cards of which only $1$ is a joker and we calculate the probability of one success. And we get $0.25242$.  But I have no idea why naming the jokers would make a difference in the second question.

Would appreciate any help.

Comment: Your result of $0.25242$ is way off. The correct answers to these two questions are approximately $\frac13$ and $\frac12$ respectively. Use [Bayes' theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayes%27_theorem) if you want exact values.

Comment: What events have you used in the Bayes theorem to get those numbers? (What is $A$ and what is $B$)

Comment: For example, in the first question, $A$ is "two jokers in Pile$1$" and $B$ is "at least one joker in Pile$1$".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps it helps to consider the $4$ a priori cases.  We will label the cases $(i,j)$ for $i,j\in \{1,2\}$, where, say, $(1,2)$ means that $J_1\in \text{Pile}_1$ and $J_2\in \text{Pile}_2$ while $(1,1)$ means that both jokers are in $\text{Pile}_1$.

The probability of each case is:

$P_{1,1}=P_{2,2}= \binom {98}{48}\big / \binom {100}{50}=.2\overline {47}$

$P_{1,2}=P_{2,1}=\binom {98}{49}\big/ \binom {100}{50}=.\overline {25}$

Sanity checks:  Note that these add to $1$ as they should, and note that we expected each case to be around $\frac 14$.

Now, your first question asks:  What is the probability that you are in case $(1,1)$ given that you are not in $(2,2)$?

The answer is, of course, $$\frac {P_{1,1}}{1-P_{2,2}}=\frac {P_{1,1}}{P_{1,1}+P_{1,2}+P_{2,1}}=.328859$$

The second question asks:  What is the probability that you are in $(1,1)$ given that you are either in $(1,1)$ or $(1,2)$?

The answer, of course, is:  $$\frac {P_{1,1}}{P_{1,1}+P_{1,2}}=.\overline {49}$$

Note that these answers are easy to justify intuitively:  if we ignore the slight dependence on the placement of the jokers, each case would have probability exactly $\frac 14$, so the answer to the first question would be $\frac 13$ while the answer to the second would be $\frac 12$.  As expected, we see that the (very minor) dependence changes the intuitive results only slightly.

Comment: So how would it look like if I wanted to get the exact numbers using Bayes formula?

Comment: I have given you the exact numbers using Bayes' Theorem.  Well, the $.328859$ is rounded down a little.

Comment: sorry, I wasn't able to see that. How did you get the probabilities for the cases?

Comment: I wrote out the computations exactly.  Since each shuffle is equally probable, it's just a matter of counting.  Note that it suffices to look at a single Pile since the contents of one Pile determine the contents of the other.

Comment: For intuition you should consider the "simpler" problem:  Suppose you toss a fair penny and a fair dime. $\#1:$ What's the probability that they both come up $H$ given that at least one of them does?    $\#2:$ What's the probability that they both come up $H$ given that the dime does?

Comment: The answer is $1/2$ for $2$

Comment: Yes, the answer to $\#2$ is $\frac 12$.

Comment: I really can't think about the first question without overwhelming my self.

Comment: Where do the questions $1$ and $2$ even differ?

Comment: Just use the same steps I followed.  For the simpler problem, it is easier to compute the probabilities of each of the $4$ cases.

Comment: [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/200807/boy-and-girl-paradox) might help with intuition.  Note too:  it's easy to do the experiment to test the computations.  All you need is two coins (or, really, just one since you can throw it twice).

Comment: So we have the $4$ cases ${(H,H),(H,T),(T,H),(T,T)}$ with prob. of $1/4$ each. In $#1$ we take out the case that don't have $H$ in them and calculate the prob. of getting another $H$ which is $1/3$

Comment: In $#2$ we have $\frac{1/4}{1/4+1/4}=1/2$

Comment: I'm still a bit fuzzy on how you got $0.\overline{25}$ for the probability of cases $2$ and $3$.

Comment: If $J_1$ is in pile $1$ then we just need to choose $49$ other cards from the $98$ non-Jokers in order to complete Pile $1$.

Comment: Thx, really helped me out a lot :D

Comment: I just thought of a different approach for the first question considering we don't differentiate between $joker_1$ and $joker_2$. We have exactly three outcomes which are $0$, $1$ or $2$ jokers in $Pile_1$. and given that we know that we already have a joker in $Pile_1$ that leaves us with two cases, of which only one has two jokers giving us a probability of $1/2$ .

Comment: @Zntzozt Well, those three cases are not equally probable (that's why I used four cases).  But, yes.  This is the same idea.  Note that it only works exactly in the case where you can disregard the dependence.

Comment: But the distinction between the jokers happens only in the second question.